# Nuxt Multiple assets emit to the same filename hot-update

Tags: nuxt.js

So I've been using Nuxt currently without Express and it was working fine. Today I have installed Nuxt again and also picked to install Express with it. Now when I do changes to the files I get this error:

[image]

Whan can cause this error ? When I restart server with `npm run dev` it works fine again until I change a file.

Comment: similar case is happening to my nuxt as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack 4.40.0 was released 12 hours ago. 4.40.1 was released about 15 minutes ago with this error mentioned in the release notes. See github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v4.40.1

Comment: Nice.. So this should work after clean install again ?

Comment: I'll try it now